# SNMP : I want to change the community name in ZT230-200dpi ZPL Zebra printer?

Tags: snmp, printer

I have an [SNMP](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) issue with the community name.

The default name is `"public"` . When I tried to change it to anther one, I find that I can walk the SNMP with two name `"public"` and `"loreal"` (giving the command `snmpwalk`) without apparent errors, like in lines below :

```
C:\>snmpwalk -v1 -c LOREAL 128.86.201.207 enterprises.683.3.3.0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.683.3.3.0 = STRING: "LOREAL"

C:\>snmpwalk -v1 -c public 128.86.201.207 enterprises.683.3.3.0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.683.3.3.0 = STRING: "LOREAL"
```

But when I use the command `snmpSET`, I can't use the new name `("LOREAL")` to change value

```
C:\>snmpset -v1 -c LOREAL 128.86.201.207 enterprises.683.3.3.0 s SWAT
Timeout: No Response from 128.86.201.207

C:\>snmpset -v1 -c public 128.86.201.207 enterprises.683.3.3.0 s SWAT
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.683.3.3.0 = STRING: "SWAT"
```

Why this happens, how can I definitively change or delete the `"public"` and use only "LOREAL" for the `snmpset/get` commands?

Notes:

- the MIB tree for [zebra printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Technologies)
- I change the community Name with ZPL II commands
- my OS win10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this issue, my problem was with the version firmware for this printers.

the model of printers is `ZT230-200dpi ZPL` and the version of firmware was `V72.19.1Z`

so when I try to change community Name with `zpl commands` , the commands were execute incorrectly.

I did upgrade the firmware to `V72.20.1Z` and I tried to send `zpl commands`

now I have response from `SNMP get/set` and I can change the values with the chosen community Name